# View deleted posts on the iOS app too?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, deleted-answers, ios-app

Instead of the reading [The Daily WTF](http://www.thedailywtf.com/)  on the daily commute, it would be nice to read *deleted* posts on the iOS app like on the main site (for users with with [moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)). Could we have this?